# My grid layout don't show any view in the layout editor

Tags: android

I have a grid layout that is a child of another layout (like frame layout or constraint layout ) . I drag and drop views on it like button or image view but it didn't show !! . How can i fix this problem ?

Picture 1:

[image]

Picture 2:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GridView works like listview and recyclerView. so, you have to add the child or data programmatically using an adapter. for example

this is the adapter

```
public class BooksAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

  private final Context mContext;
  private final Book[] books;

  // 1
  public BooksAdapter(Context context, Book[] books) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.books = books;
  }

  // 2
  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return books.length;
  }

  // 3
  @Override
  public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
  }

  // 4
  @Override
  public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
  }

  // 5
  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView dummyTextView = new TextView(mContext);
    dummyTextView.setText(String.valueOf(position));
    return dummyTextView;
  }

}
```

and this in your activity

```
GridView gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview);
BooksAdapter booksAdapter = new BooksAdapter(this, books);
gridView.setAdapter(booksAdapter);
```

see this for more information
https://www.raywenderlich.com/995-android-gridview-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

A [GridView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview) needs an [Adapter](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout#AdapterViews) in order to work dinamically, this is for programatically populating the `GridView` i.e. show content depending on calculations, data sources, interactions, etc. If you just want to arrange images statically in the form of a grid, you can create `Views` and `ViewGroups` and change their properties in the xml file like padding, margin, gravity, etc. in order to fix them within a layout.